# What's the correct type for a variable in TypeScript that's initially undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a variable we'll call `a` in this example:

```
let a;
```

I only want to assign it a value if it meets one of the requirements in the switch statement:

```
switch(someOtherVar) {
  case "a": {
    a = "123";
    break;
  }
  case "b": {
    a = "456";
    break;
  }
}
```

I then want to check if it has a value like so:

```
if (a) {
  // ...do something
}
```

This means `a` can be a `string` or `undefined`, and it starts `undefined`. If I don't declare the type then it throws the following error:

> Variable 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type, but a better type may be inferred from usage.ts(7043)

I'm not sure what the correct way to declare the type would be in this instance:

```
1. let a: string | undefined; // this seems to be the best way
2. let a = undefined; // this declares it as any which I don't want
3: let a: string; // is this correct if it can be undefined?
```

Comment: You are putting the carriage in front of the horses. Don't try to figure out the correct type of a variable from its usage. Find the type from the semantic of the variable, use the type to declare the variable and initialize the variable in the declaration according to its type. What is the purpose of `a` in your program? Is it a description? Then its type is `string`. Is it a price? Then its type is `number`. Is it a flag that drives the code behaviour? Then it is a `boolean`. And so on and so forth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct type is `string | undefined`. Under `srictNullChecks`, the type `string` does not contain the `undefined` value or the `null` value. These two values have their own types `undefined` and `null`. So to have a variable that is `string` or `undefined` using a union is appropriate.

Note that control flow analysis does a pretty good job of inferring the type  for your specific use case if the variable is not referenced in a closure

```
let a = undefined; // any here 

switch(someOtherVar) {
  case "a": {
    a = "123";
    break;
  }
  case "b": {
    a = "456";
    break;
  }
}
// function x() { console.log(a)}; // if referenced in another function you get an error

a; // but the type of a is string | undefined
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA3W8DOB7AtiA8gFwAsQYA1FALjTxgEsA7AcwCgIQ94p4BeeAVztAAzeiGABuJk1QB3GnjAEAFBmz4ipWAEp4Abybx4YKKgQAiKKcp6DBzj1MBGAEwBmUxJvwARnCgBrD3gAX31DYzMvS11Q2254UwAWAFYANncY718A0JCQgHo8+EF+MDwadDp4AA9FbR1DCoxWADoIdAZFKE0gsXgC+BpBeDhBYhA6MFEByqg6dEJiIpKyivgAT3ReeAY2DkriGHQYSShe-tRqegZ4AB8+ARBhOimgA)

Answer (score 0):

Your first suggestion is correct because `a` can't be `any`.

You second suggestion still has the type `any`. You would need to it as follows but that's basically the same as your first suggestion.

```
let a: string | undefined = undefined;
```

Your third suggestion will cause problems because the engine does not expect the value to be undefined.

If you know it's a string, you could declare it as empty string and later check the length of the string.

```
let a: string = "";
```

```
if (a.length > 0) {
  // do something...
}
```

Comment: Don't use `String` use `string`